# Invalid Hash returned from functions.storage.ObjectMetadata.md5Hash

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, md5

I have a cloud function that creates a new document in firestore once a cloudbuild completes.

```
    export const onNewFirmwareBuild = functions.storage.bucket(FIRMWARE_BUCKET).object().onFinalize(async (object) => {

    await admin.firestore()
        .collection('products').doc(PRODUCT)  
        .collection('firmware').add({
            fullname: object.name,
            md5Hash: object.md5Hash
        });
  );
```

The hash value is:

> c/9/vkntQHBsRhRA7r+l1w==

It is not valid md5Hash because it doesn't have [128 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and includes illegal characters.

However the hash is correct in the artifacts.json.

Why is the hash value wrong?  Is there a work around, or an easy way to take the hash from the .json and add it to the document?

Comment: what is the size of your file?

Comment: Its only small - 500kb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are receiving the raw MD5 (no hex value) encoded to a base64 of your file.

Is necessary to decode your hash and convert the decoded string into hex value for example

```
Md5 from google
"c/9/vkntQHBsRhRA7r+l1w==" 

decoded and hex value:
"73ff7fbe49ed40706c461440eebfa5d7"
```

I used this CyberChef [recipe](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',true)To_Hex('None')&input=Yy85L3ZrbnRRSEJzUmhSQTdyK2wxdz09) to convert the MD5 base64

Comment: Extracting the md5Hash from the metadata using your linked code yields the same result...

Comment: I will update my answer, I found that the value of the MD5 from cloud storage is on base 64 and is necessary to convert the result to hex

Comment: Buffer.from(object.md5Hash, 'base64').toString('hex');